# Why Yii2 Captcha ignores {image} in template

Tags: php, yii2, recaptcha

I've got this captch template:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode', [
'template' => '
    <div class="mb-4 field-signupform-verification required">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 align-items-center w-100">{input}{image}</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
    </div>
',])->widget(Captcha::class, [
   'imageOptions' => [
   'alt' => 'Captcha',
   'title' => 'Click to refresh',
   'style' => 'cursor: pointer',
   'class' => 'ml-auto',
   ],
   'options' => [
   'placeholder' => 'Code from picture',
   ],
   ]) ?>
```

The problem is that {image} in template is completely ignored and it just echoes `{image}` as html text. Although there is an image but it's on the left side from input but I want it on the right. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `$form->field(...)->widget(Captcha::class, ...)` you are using `yii\captcha\Captcha` as input widget inside of `yii\widgets\ActiveField`. Any options passed in `field()` method are options for `ActiveField` widget, not for the `Captcha` widget. And `ActiveField` widget doesn't recognize `{image}` in its template because both, input field and image are generated by `Captcha` widget. So you need to split your template into two parts. First part would be your wrapping html that you will set in the `field()` method options. The second part would be image and input order that you will set in your `widget()` method options:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode', [
    'template' => '
        <div class="mb-4 field-signupform-verification required">
            <div class="d-flex gap-2 align-items-center w-100">{input}</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>',
])->widget(Captcha::class, [
    'template' => '{input} {image}',
    'imageOptions' => [
        'alt' => 'Captcha',
        'title' => 'Click to refresh',
        'style' => 'cursor: pointer',
        'class' => 'ml-auto',
    ],
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Code from picture',
    ],
]) ?>
```